# Netboot a machine, automatically rsync internal HDD to network master and continue booting from internal HDD

Tags: rsync, initramfs, overlayfs

I have a server which stores the master image for a set of client computers.
As of now the clients netboot from the server and use an overlayfs, so any changes do not affect the master image.

Changes to the master image, can now result in undefined behavior, which is only fixed by a reboot of the clients. Also the clients are 100% dependent on the server, which means they are no usable if the server goes down for maintenance.

I would therefore like the clients to have a local copy of the master image, which is updated regularly e.g. upon boot.

What I envision is the following

- The client boot over the network and get the kernel and initramfs from the server
- It then synchronizes its internal HDD with a master image on the server
- It continues booting with an overlayfs (so the copy of the master images does not change)

If possible i would like to avoid to much manual work. Much like I use the `overlayroot` package to take care of all the overlayfs stuff.

Comment: I am adding my comment back.  This is just a thought I had. I have never really used the overlayfs over a network, but if your server does have the `append initrd=` line for PXEbooting I believe all you need to do is to add on a `toram` option before the dashes at the end of the line that will force the copying to the client RAM so that if the server does go down the client OS running is no longer dependent on the server. That option is used for USB booting as well where you can pull USB drive and still run a full install.  I don't know if this will affect the overlayfs or not.

Comment: This sounds interesting. I will have a look!

Comment: If you can, add it to the `pxelinux.cfg/default` file if that is what you are using to start the netboot from.

Comment: I created a custom configuration `pxelinux.cfg/C0A8010A` (`C0A8010A` = 192.168.1.10 being the hex ip address of one client). The `toram` option did not seem to have any effect. I will do some debugging.
Anyhow, loading everything to ram is not ideal, as the image is 60GB (some bulky commercial software in there). Copying everything over on every boot would take a long time, and occupy large portions of the RAM.